# jquery.js not referencing properly within Perl Template Toolkit-generated files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, perl, template-toolkit

I have an extremely simple little JavaScript/Perl CGI example that I've used to get started with a larger project. When I run it as `client.html` and `server.pl`, it works flawlessly. However, when I change the `client.html` to `client.tmpl`, and call it from the same `server.pl` script using Template Toolkit, it can't seem to find jQuery functions.

I have even created a `master.tmpl` file, and used `[% INCLUDE client.html %]` inside it, and it fails. The browser console verifies that the path to `jquery.js` is correct, but it's like it fails to load it when it's inside a template.

The following is the HTML file that I'm essentially trying to turn into a `.tmpl` file (formatting messed up, first time here, sorry):

#### client.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AJAX Example</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script src="http://domainname/ajax_example/jquery.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function myTimer() {
            var typingTimer;
            var doneTypingInterval = 2000;

            $("#user_text").keyup( function() {

               clearTimeout(typingTimer);

               if ( $('#user_text' ).val()) {
                   typingTimer = setTimeout(updateText, doneTypingInterval);
               }
            });

            function updateText() {

                var current_text = document.getElementById('user_text').value;
                var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

                http.onreadystatechange = function() {

                    if ( http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200 ) {
                        var response = http.responseText;
                        document.getElementById('server_response').value = response;
                    }
                };

                http.open("GET", "http://domainname/ajax_example/cgi-bin/server.pl?user_text=" + current_text , true );

                http.send();
            }
        }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>Input Text: <input type="text" id="user_text" name="user_text"  onkeyup="myTimer()"/></div><br/>
        <div>Server Resp.: <textarea id="server_response"  name="server_response"> </textarea></div>
        <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `server.pl` that works:

#### server.pl

```
$cgi = CGI->new;
$id = $cgi->param('user_text');
$result = uc($id);
print $cgi->header();
print $result;
```

The `server.pl` that doesn't work:

#### server.pl

```
$cgi = CGI->new;
$id = $cgi->param('user_text');
**returned from result calculation sub** $result = uc($id);

my $config = {
    EVAL_PERL    => 1,
    POST_CHOMP   => 1,
    INTERPOLATE => 1,
    INCLUDE_PATH => '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/ajax_example/:/var/www/html/ajax_example/',  
};

    print $cgi->header( -charset=>'utf-8' );
    my $tt = Template->new($config);
    $tt->process('client.tmpl', \$result);
}
```

Keep in mind, I am trying my best to summarize the code, but the Perl and JavaScript work just fine, unless it's being used through TT.  The error is:

```
#user_text.keyup is not a function:
("#user_text").keyup(function(){
```

Same error I would get if I put in a bad path to `jquery.js`.  The path is good though, without a doubt.

Thank you for any recommendations anyone can provide.

Comment: What's the difference between the working HTML and the generated HTML? What's the difference in the URLs between the working HTML and the generated HTML?

Comment: Where is the `$` for jquery in that last snippet?

Comment: There is literally no difference in the two HTML files, except that one is a .tmpl file called by Template Toolkit, and the other is a .html file called directly by the browser without going through TT.  simbabque, I'm sorry I don't understand the question.  The last snippet is an error message generated by the browser console.  It has picked that line from the javascript in the code above as being the problem.  However, it works just fine in that exact form when called outside of a TT generated HTML page.

Comment: Turn off INTERPOLATE, it treats $ as the beginning of a perl variable name. Also turn off EVAL_PERL, you're not using any [% PERL %] blocks in your template. In fact, you really shouldn't be generating JavaScript with templates in the first place; just use a static file and leave the templates for your HTML.

Comment: Wow, it was that simple.  I was using both of those things in a previous project, and copied and pasted that portion into this one to get started.  Didn't even consider that the interpolation was affecting the Javascript.  Thank you Mr. Manifestation of Borat.  You have been my savior.

Comment: @JeffreyTackett: I hope you have learned from this to write only code that has a function that you can explain. Boilerplate code has a place, but it should never be a "black box" to you.

Comment: Heh.  I appreciate that Borodin, and your help is definitely much appreciated as well ... truly.  That said, I don't have the luxury of delaying results until I've learned all that I need to learn about another language.  Passable critical thinking skills, some moderate Perl experience, and an unmatched will to search, read, and experiment has allowed me to accomplish the goals required of me over the last month.  Once the urgency subsides, I'll have to time to finish the Udemy classes I started 3 weeks ago.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you have enabled the `INTERPOLATE` option, which interpolates Perl variables anywhere in the template. That makes the module attempt to replace `$(` by its value, and destroys the JavaScript syntax

It's a sloppy way of using templates anyway: you should pass all the values you need in the `$vars` hash, and extract them from there using `[% variable %]` template directives. The same applies to the `EVAL_PERL` option, as any complex data manipulation should ordinarily be in the code that calls `process`. Everything you need to do inside the template is available as a Template directive

Talking of the `$vars` hash, you should be getting `Not a HASH reference` errors, because you are passing to `process` a reference to the string variable `$result` instead of a hash containing that value. It's unclear how you want that value to be handled, but the only mention of `id` in your HTML is the `id` attribute of the `<input>` element at the bottom of the HTML, so I've put a directive in their to show you how it all works

Take a look at this code

#### CGI program

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use CGI;
use Template;

my $cgi    = CGI->new;
my $id     = $cgi->param('user_text') // 'abc123';
my $result = uc $id;

print $cgi->header( -charset => 'utf-8' );

my $tt = Template->new( {
    # INCLUDE_PATH => '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/ajax_example/:/var/www/html/ajax_example/', 
    POST_CHOMP   => 1,
} );

$tt->process('client.html', { result => $result } );
```

I have modified your HTML file like this. I couldn't tell what you wanted to do with the value that the CGI code pulls from the `user_text` parameter, so I put it into a `value` attribute for the first input field

#### Template file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <title>AJAX Example</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        <script src="http://domainname/ajax_example/jquery.js" />

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function myTimer() {

                var typingTimer;
                var doneTypingInterval = 2000;

                $("#user_text").keyup( function() {

                   clearTimeout(typingTimer);

                   if ( $('#user_text' ).val() ) {
                       typingTimer = setTimeout(updateText, doneTypingInterval);
                   }
                } );

                function updateText() {

                    var current_text = document.getElementById('user_text').value;
                    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    http.onreadystatechange = function() {

                        if ( http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200 ) {
                            var response = http.responseText;
                            document.getElementById('server_response').value = response;
                        }
                    };

                    http.open("GET",
                        "http://domainname/ajax_example/cgi-bin/server.pl?user_text=" + current_text,
                        true );

                    http.send();
                }
            }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div>Input Text:
            <input type="text" id="user_text" name="user_text" value="[% result %]" onkeyup="myTimer()"/>
        </div>
        <br/>

        <div>Server Resp.:
            <textarea id="server_response"  name="server_response"/>
        </div>
        <br/>

    </body>

</html>
```

And here's the resulting output from the CGI code. As you can see, the `$("#user_text").keyup` call remains intact, and the value from the CGI code—the `result` element passed in the `$vars` hash—has been substituted into the `value` attribute of the text `input` element

I hope this helps you to progress and get your application working

#### output

```html
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <title>AJAX Example</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        <script src="http://domainname/ajax_example/jquery.js" />

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function myTimer() {

                var typingTimer;
                var doneTypingInterval = 2000;

                $("#user_text").keyup( function() {

                   clearTimeout(typingTimer);

                   if ( $('#user_text' ).val() ) {
                       typingTimer = setTimeout(updateText, doneTypingInterval);
                   }
                } );

                function updateText() {

                    var current_text = document.getElementById('user_text').value;
                    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    http.onreadystatechange = function() {

                        if ( http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200 ) {
                            var response = http.responseText;
                            document.getElementById('server_response').value = response;
                        }
                    };

                    http.open("GET",
                        "http://domainname/ajax_example/cgi-bin/server.pl?user_text=" + current_text,
                        true );

                    http.send();
                }
            }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div>Input Text:
            <input type="text" id="user_text" name="user_text" value="ABC123" onkeyup="myTimer()"/>
        </div>
        <br/>

        <div>Server Resp.:
            <textarea id="server_response"  name="server_response"/>
        </div>
        <br/>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks.  I am sure the reason I'm not seeing the error you spoke of is due to some of the processing stuff I left out for the sake of simplicity.  I appreciate you going above and beyond to assist.  Very cool.  Everything works great without INTERPOLATE turned on, and per Suit's recommendation above, I moved the javascript to an external file.  Some minor tweaks from the above information, and I believe I'm good to go. Thank you again.  Much appreciated.